# Unable to add a Web Part Page to Pages document library in WSS 3.0

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0

I am unable to Create a new Web Part Page in the Pages document library of my site collection. It shows the following error:

```
An error has occurred on the server.
```

Please help, where to start looking for the cause ?

```
EDIT: I get the following entries in the 12\Logs folder:
```

Timestamp               Process                                     TID     Area                            Category                        EventID Level       Message     Correlation
06/28/2011 13:12:35.07  wsstracing.exe (0x15E4)                     0x107C  ULS Logging                     Unified Logging Service         8gsv    Monitorable perfmon disabled for this process
06/28/2011 13:12:35.07  wsstracing.exe (0x15E4)                     0x107C  ULS Logging                     Unified Logging Service         8wsv    High        ULS Init Completed (wsstracing.exe, ONETNA~1.DLL)
06/28/2011 13:12:35.07  wsstracing.exe (0x15E4)                     0x1748  ULS Logging                     Unified Logging Service         5152    Information Tracing Service started.
06/28/2011 13:15:29.90  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0998)                       0x0E44  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         0   Medium      Entering MRU trim routine.
06/28/2011 13:15:29.90  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0998)                       0x0E44  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         0   Medium      Initial table size: 0 in 0 entries
06/28/2011 13:15:29.90  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0998)                       0x0E44  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         0   Medium      Final table size: 0 in 0 entries
06/28/2011 13:15:29.90  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0998)                       0x0E44  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         0   Medium      Exiting MRU trim routine.

I am able to create new Sites though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by disabling the friendly errors, you do this by opening the web.config and modifying the line…

```
<SafeMode MaxControls="200" CallStack="false"…
```

to…

```
<SafeMode MaxControls="200" CallStack="true"…
```

You will also need to set custom errors to 'Off' .

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

When done with that we can start narrowing your problem!

Comment: In that case you need to have a look on the other config files located in the realms of c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\. Getting the stacktrace is the no1 priority to solve this

Comment: I have done it in all the web.configs inside \12 folder as well in wss\virtualDirectories folder. Still I see the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do the same in Web.config under Layouts directory, as CreatePage.aspx is a layout page.

Also, you should look at the logs under 12 hive. Even if you are seeing custom error on screen, actual error will get logged in logs folder. 
You should also check Event Viewer (Application Events) for any application error that might have occurred.